# Is it possible to send localStorage data, and then retrieve it again? AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

My scenario is this: I have a very small array in my js file. When the page loads up, I have a function that loops through the array, and generates an li element for each item in the array, displaying it's name and price in the li. The array is constructed like this:

```
var gameList = [
{ name: "", value: 0.00},
]
```

Secondly, I have a simple form on the page that allows me to add new items to the array, and using localStorage, it's possible for me to keep a dynamically updated array. I push new items into the array (gameList), then at the end of the session I set it using localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem("updatedGameList", JSON.stringify(gameList));
```

I have a couple of lines at the start of my code that sets my original array 'gameList' to be equal to the locally stored, updated game list.

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("updatedGameList");
gameList = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

So this is fine for now, but the growing array - which I want to keep and maintain - is only available in this browser, on this machine.

So, my question is, can I send this locally stored data somewhere? Maybe my personal domain? (Which is where I will host the app when it's finished) That way I could then reference it properly in my js file so that the data is always available? Maybe the array could have it's own js file?

I realise that this may not be the best way to be handling what is essentially a database. But I'm only part way through an online course and I'm using the tools that I have to make this work.

And lastly, in terms of maintenance of the array, is there any way to send it back to sublime in the form a .js file? I know this could be a crazy question. The updated array will become pretty big, maybe 200 items eventually, and it would be much easier to maintain from within sublime.

Thanks for your time, and apologies if part of this request is ridiculous!! :)

I have just been reading about AJAX, and thought maybe there's a way to send the updated array as a json file to somewhere(!) on my website, and then request that same file at the start of each new session, so I'm always working with, and saving, the latest updated array.

Thanks for reading, and hopefully you have some answers! :)

Comment: if you want to send and retrieve data to a server, AJAX is one way of doing it

Comment: if you're going to send it to the server, there's no point in also putting it in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Fair point Barmar! I should add, I was working remotely on this app, on a train, and was working in the console when I figured the localStorage stuff. I'd just updated the array by about 30 records or so, and was just relieved that I had a way to not completely lose the data. It's in progress, but usable, which is why the original array is so small.

Also, Jaromander X, could you show how I might send and retrieve this data, bearing in mind that the data I want to send is currently only held in localStorage?

Comment: @Doughballs on SO if you want to specify who you are talking to, you must prepend @ to their name at the start of the comment.  This way an alert is sent to their account.

Comment: @JaromandaX please see Doughballs' comment to you.

Comment: @mickmackusa - wow ...  that was 7 weeks ago ... and I lost interest 6 weeks, 23 hours and 30 minutes ago :p my comment stands as is, I'm not going to write it for him :p

Comment: Agreed.  This question's status is stuck/abandoned at "_RTM & DIY_" .  @Doughballs You should either update your question with a specific issue to correct or delete this question.

Comment: Ok. Let me apologise for my tardiness, I'm not au fait with the protocol on here but I certainly am now, thanks to you guys, and I will be better the next time I ask a question!

Here's what I settled on. Each time I used the app, and I added to the array, I saved this locally, and then updated my js file to refer to this new larger array each time. And then for backup I copied the new array into a separate js file, in case I accidentally shut the window and lost the data. It's still the temporary solution until I get to the mongo module.

My real question was can I automate this step.

Comment: And finally, let me thank @mickmackusa :)

Comment: @JaromandaX and @ Barmar Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not quite what I was looking for - essentially some way of automatically getting the new array, sending it somewhere more secure than local storage, then referencing the new array to give me the most up to date starting point each time (and all with just javascript) - the 'dirty' way suggested below turned out to be sufficient for now until I start using databases.

From Kirupa, over at the forums:

Not a ridiculous question at all! You can send your own data anywhere you want, but it will require some level of server-related code. The easiest way to send data back and forth is through JSON, and you can convert your array into a JSON format easily using something like the following:

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(myArray);
From here, you can send this data to a database, to another web site, or to your e-mail server. If you want something really quick and dirty, you can literally just copy the contents of your JSON-ized array using the Chrome Dev Tools, save it on disk as a .js file, and reference it again in your app. That is a manual way of doing something that you don't really care about automating.

The best solution is to store this in a database. They've gotten easier to deal with as well. Firebase is my go-to for things like this, and this video might give you some ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE

Comment: Sounds like a winner. Award it a green tick?

Comment: Cheers @mickmackusa ! :)